# Argument is not named in hc_add_series

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I use the package highcharter to create the plot below with:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type="column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type="category") %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Things",
    data = list(
      list(
        name = "Animals",
        y = 10,
        drilldown = "animals"
      ),
      list(
        name = "People",
        y = 10,
        drilldown = "people"
      )
    )
  )
hc
```

[image]

When I try to create the similar plot fot the sum of `Nu`m for every US State I get:

```
argument is not named in hc_add_series
```

## data

```
State <- c("ALABAMA", "ALABAMA", "ALASKA", "ALASKA")
Num <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
d <- data.frame(State, Num)
```

## code

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type="column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type="category") %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "States",
    output2 <- d %>% group_by(State) %>%
      summarise(Num = sum(Num)) %>%
      mutate(drilldown = tolower(State)) %>% 
      transpose 
  )
```

Why does this happen since in both cases Im using a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can benefit from using `hcaes` which works like `aes` in `ggplot`:

```
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(type="column") %>%
hc_xAxis(type="category") %>%
hc_add_series(
    data = d,
    name = "States",
    type = "column",
    hcaes(x = State, y = Num)
  )
```